# android how to use setLayoutDirection in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use `LTR` (left to right) and `RTL` (right to left) in my application.

I read this post http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

I search a lot in order to know how to use this function in android 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no LTR/RTL support in Android 2.2. In fact, there is no RTL language support *at all* in Android 2.2 -- IIRC, they didn't even begin RTL language support until 2.3 or 3.0.

Hence, you are on your own to create whatever sort of RTL framework that you want to use for Android 2.2 through 4.1.

Comment: if there is no such a support so have i make a new layout for all my old layouts? like we do with application multi language ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: I guess so. Since I am not quite certain how you are handling RTL *languages* decently on 2.2, I can only guess as to what the correct answer would be for RTL *layouts* on 2.2.

Comment: I mean to use a folder called `layout-ar` for all my layouts in arabic, right?

Comment: please tell me, i am in hurry

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: You are welcome to give that a try. Unfortunately, Google removed the roster of supported languages from their release notes, and so I do not know whether `-ar` will be recognized as a language code or not. It is certainly worth a try.

Comment: thanks for your answer, for `-ar` it is working , and i am trying it right now, but i  just wanted to know if this is the good way that you know it for layouts 2.2 directions

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use `ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(View view, int layoutDirection)` for APIs<17